# Unable to input text in an input field (in a fancy box popup)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, fancybox

for some reason I can't input text in my newsletter input field now that I display it in a [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) popup window. Any idea what the issue is and how to fix this? See http://jsfiddle.net/6G8YR/
Many thanks,

```
function openFancybox() {
    setTimeout( function() {$('#newspopup').trigger('click'); },1000);

}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited');
    if (visited == 'yes') {
        return false;
    } else {
        openFancybox();
    }
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 0.0001 });
    $('#newspopup').fancybox({
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.3)'
            }
        }
    }
});

});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target === $('.visitwebsitebtn')[0]) {
        $.fancybox.close();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured out the problem, but only ran into other kinds of issues. The problem is that, there is an event that exists that causes your fancybox to refresh everytime someone happens to click on it.

This is why you are unable to write anything in the input. I have a temporary solution that is really ugly but it works.

```
$('#email').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Upon clicking the email input, your fancybox won't refersh. I tried applying this to your *#newspopup* but it blocs *$('#newspopup').trigger('click');* so your fancybox never opens at the start.

Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/6G8YR/2/)

**Additional information:**

I've worked with fancybox plugin before and I've never encountered this problem. You might want to think of adding options to your fancybox.. for example add this line :

```
'type':'iframe',
```

I would have tried on jsfiddle, but unfortunately they don't allow it, it seems.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the temporary solution works! Where would you add the 'type':'iframe', in my code? (sorry I'm a beginner in JS). Many thanks

Comment: .fancybox({'type':'iframe', helper...}); and no problem. =]

Answer (score 2):

You can optimize your code and get rid of unnecessary `click` events and triggers (so you won't need unnecessary `e.stopPropagation()` methods either) like :

```
function openFancybox() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.fancybox('#newspopup', {
            modal: true, // this prevents fancybox to close unless close unless ".visitwebsitebtn" is clicked
            helpers: {
                overlay: {
                    css: {
                        'background': 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.3)'
                    }
                }
            },
            afterShow: function () {
                // enables a way to close fancybox
                $(".visitwebsitebtn").on("click", function () {
                    $.fancybox.close()
                });
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited');
    if (visited == 'yes') {
        return false;
    } else {
        openFancybox();
    }
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', {
        expires: 7
    });
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/88X6D/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Appreciate it